# Drupal 7 Node Revisions per Role

Tags: 7, nodes

I have created a new role '**news contributor**'.
I have created a new content type '**news**'.

The '**news contributor**' role has permissions enabled to view, revert, delete **revisions**.
However, this setting also gives them access to view, revert, delete revisions on ALL nodes.

[image]

How can i restrict node revisions on specific content types based on user role and content type?

The '**news contributor**' should only be able to tinker with revisions for the '**news**' content type and nothing else.

At the moment they have access to revision any node which is undesirable.

Has anyone had this issue before and, how did you resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across this issue on a site and with drupal core revisions this is next to impossible.  We resorted to using a great module called Revisioning which allows role based revisioning and can tighten who can publish revisions.  You are able to grant permission to a specific role to publish while other roles can have the ability to create revisions.  This can be for specific content types as well.  Also you have the ability to "revert" revisions if you want.

https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning

Comment: I was looking at that module but hesitated to download it because i wasn't sure core would provide me this ability. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but there is a relatively new module with a stable 7.x release that looks like it was built only for this purpose: [Node revision Permissions Per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_per_role)

> Node revision Permissions Per Role allows to give roles administer per content type node revision permissions without giving them full administer nodes permission.
>
> For instance, you may let certain users(eg: roles:External-blogger ) manage node revision of a specific content type(eg: blog) but restrict to manage node revision of all other content type that this module is perfectly works for you.